# PDF2IMAGE - Path not found

Tags: python, pdf2image

I have problem with convert using pdf2image module.
I don't know where is something wrong with the code.
When I run program and paste path the error shows.

Code below:

```
import os
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

 
 
def convert():
    try:
        for img in images:
            for idx, img in enumerate(images, start=1):
                img.save(os.path.join(os.cudir,'new_folder',f"image_{idx}.jpg"))


    except:
        Result = "FileNotFoundError"
        messagebox.showinfo("Result", Result)

    else:
        Result = "success"
        messagebox.showinfo("Result", Result)
 
 
 
master = Tk()
Label(master, text="File Location").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
 
e1 = Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
 
b = Button(master, text="Convert", command=convert)
b.grid(row=0, column=2,columnspan=2, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=5)
  
mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovWHu.png)

Comment: You should save the error that is being caught, and print it out. It likely has information that will tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess, but does the folder `os.path.join(os.cudir,'new_folder')` already exist? This code seems to assume it does.

Try printing more information about the error:

```
    except Exception as e:
        Result = f"FileNotFoundError: {e}"
        messagebox.showinfo("Result", Result)
```